# How to allow execution of an applet without prompting the user?

Tags: java, security, applet

I have an applet selfsigned that always requires the user allow its execution. Is it possible to allow this applet to run without user confirmation? It's for an intranet application used at most by 10 people, so it's possible to create a short guide to install certificate or something else on these desktop pc. 
I tried using the following manifest entries

```
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: all-permissions
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: *Is it possible to allow this applet to run without user confirmation?* **No**. Because, there were too many problems with security.

Comment: *"I have an applet selfsigned that always requires the user allow its execution."* I'm surprised you can find a combo. of browser and Java version that allows a self signed applet to launch at all!